# How to rotate large database of images, and store each rotation as new image?

Tags: database, image, macos

I am trying to take a database of images, rotate them 1 degree at a time, and then save each tilt as a new picture. Does anyone know how I can do this? I am on a Mac.

Comment: Knowing which database you are using would help. Knowing which programming languages you are familiar with would help. Knowing what you have tried would help. Knowing why you would want to do such a thing would be interesting.

Comment: I am using a database of JPG files. I am most familiar with python. I tried an image tilting script in python, but it was taking too long. I am trying to do this for a machine learning algorithm.

Comment: You still didn't name the database. You do realise it will make your database around 500x bigger for no benefit since you can readily generate all the other 359 images anyway - without storing them.

Comment: Why would you actually even bother storing images in a database? What would be the benefit? Surely it will just make the database large and unwieldy to back up and make it hard to view the images without writing SQL or using some sort of interface you'd have to write - whereas if you stored the images in a filesystem you could readily view them, edit them, back them up and access them?

Comment: Thanks! I think that's a better idea!

Comment: Do you plan to use `OpenCV` and have you got it set up and running under Xcode?

Comment: I'm using tensorflow, and it's working under Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in `sips` command in the Terminal:

```
sips -r 10 input.jpg --out output.jpg
```

The above will rotate `input.jpg` 10 degrees clockwise and save the result as `output.jpg`.

I would start from zero each time and rotate by 1 degree, then by 2 degrees, then by 3 degrees rather than keep doing 1 degree increments otherwise errors will probably accumulate.

You can get help on `sips` by typing

```
man sips
```

Spacebar advances a page, `q` will quit.

[Online help.](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html)